# Applying header and implementation files for subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, header, view, implementation

You can create a subview with

```
myView *newView = [[myView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

And you have the implementation and header files for it too. However, the views don't just automatically pop up in the storyboard. How do I assign header and implementation files to a view I have added in the storyboard?
I am very new to Objective-C and iOS Development, so try not to be too complicated or technical.

Comment: "I am very new to Obj C and iOS Development" yet you correctly **not** tagged your question as Xcode. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, drag in a Custom View, and then on the Identity Inspector for this view, in the Custom Class section, select your class.